# Why is Vagrant port forwarding not working

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a Vagrant box with JBoss. I'm trying to forward two ports. My `Vagrantfile` has the following for that

```
web.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080 # jboss
web.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9990, host: 9990 # jboss management console
```

On `vagrant up web` I can see in console

```
==> web: Forwarding ports...
    web: 8080 => 8080 (adapter 1)
    web: 9990 => 9990 (adapter 1)
```

When I do `netstat` ports seem to be ok

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep VirtualBox
[sudo] password for ostraaten: 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9990            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21241/VirtualBox
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2222          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21241/VirtualBox
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21241/VirtualBox
```

When I do `curl -v http://localhost:8080` on the Vagrant box itself, this works fine. I see the JBoss stuff.

When I do `curl -v https://localhost:8080` on the host other stuff happens.

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8080
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8080/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

There is no firewall running on the Vagrant box.

Configuration for forwarding ports at first seems trivial but it now looks like there is more to it. How should this work?

Comment: Are you sure the firewall does not work?

Comment: Try changing your host port. Could be that you already have something there?

Comment: web.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8088 # jboss

Comment: It must be the firewall

Comment: What about a firewall or other security software on your host machine? Also, do you have more than one Vagrant box running? e.g. it's Vbox listening, but is it maybe for another VM?

Comment: There is no firewall on the Vagrant box or the host. I think this issue is related to VirtualBox networking code. Configuration is trivial but the code is buggy so it is not expected to work for some.

Comment: Make sure your JBoss is binding to 0.0.0.0 instead of just localhost.

Comment: It's way too late, but did it ever fix mate? and if so care to share please if you remember?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little too late, but I just encountered an issue similar to this, however I am using Sinatra. After a little research, and as what Al Jacinto said I found out that running your ruby app like this:

```
ruby app.rb -o 0.0.0.0
```

(http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html)

should solve the problem without the need to edit ruby.rb
I apologize if this is not related somehow but I thought that it might give a hint!